# React renderComponent replace DOM

Tags: reactjs

JSX code:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div className="darken">hello world</div>
  }
});
React.renderComponent(<App/>, document.querySelector('.main'))
```

HTML:

```
<body>
  <header>welcome</header>
  <div class="main"></div>
</body>
```

`React.renderComponent` will append rendered JSX to `<div class="main">`. Output of HTML will be:

```
<body>
  <header>welcome</header>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="darken">hello world</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is it possible `React.renderComponent` replace `<div class="main">`, so what I expect like this:

```
<body>
  <header>welcome</header>
  <div class="darken">hello world</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Was having a problem getting my component to render in React 0.14.0. My solution was make sure your scripts have a special type:

```
<script type="text/babel" src='js/app.js'></script>
```

Include these three libraries:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
```

Then use `ReactDOM.render()`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<Timer start={Date.now()} />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

I'm not even using ES6 or a build system. Simple solution to get text on the screen with react.js

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just use:

```
React.render(<App/>, document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't think this way before. But now I have some situations and I have update question (look at HTML code).. Can you solve my problem?

Comment: I'm pretty sure React can only render top components inside containers, they cannot replace existing elements. Of course, you could just remove your old element manually before rendering the React component.

Comment: But that is not possible, if you remove the old element before rendering the React component you'll get the error: "Target container is not a DOM element.".

Comment: What you could do is to render the React component and then replace the parent node with the just rendered children node, but I'm not sure if that is going to mess with React's events.

$(document).ready(function(){
    React.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.main'));
    var $main = $('.main');
    var $darken = $($main.find('.darken'));
    $main.replaceWith($darken);
  });

Comment: @p1nox yes it will mess React's events .. react will complain all the time about changed root element.. looking for solution too

Comment: They are looking for a solution too https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1311 , BTW my solution is pretty hacky :P.

Comment: Please note, the `renderComponent` method has been renamed to `render` in version 0.12 of React so the above answer might not work for you in newer versions of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem and this is what I came up with.
Replace it with a simple span tag so it doesn't affect your styling.

```
const appContainer = document.createElement('span')
const mainEl = document.querySelector('.main')
mainEl.parentNode.replaceChild(appContainer, mainEl)
React.renderComponent(<App/>, mainEl)
```

Which will produce

```
<body>
  <header>welcome</header>
  <span> <!-- this acts as the container for react -->
    <div class="darken">hello world</div>
  </span>
</body>
```